# 3D Touch Shortcuts Stopped Working - Xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, 3dtouch

Since updating my Xcode Project to Swift 3 in Xcode 8 my 3D Touch shortcuts no longer work where they previously did. Do I need to change something in my code to get these working again?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to Xcode 8 beta 8 fixed this issue.

**Edit 1:**

Changing the line:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, performActionFor shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: (Bool) -> Void) {
    let handledShortCutItem = handleShortCutItem(shortcutItem)

    completionHandler(handledShortCutItem)
}
```

to:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, performActionFor shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    let handledShortCutItem = handleShortCutItem(shortcutItem)

    completionHandler(handledShortCutItem)
}
```

(Added the `@escaping`)